# R - partial match in reading lines from file

Tags: regex, r

I have a file.txt like this that I want to read in R until some match is found:

```
header1
header2
more descriptions
again
stop here
dataline1             
dataline2
dataline3
```

in this case the match would be "stop here".

I want to do this the following way:

```
x<-file("file.txt","r")
match<-paste("stop","here")
line<-readLines(x,1)
while(line!=match){
        line<-readLines(x,1)
}

line
[1] "stop here"
```

The problem is that the stopping line can have more strings, that is, besides "stop here" can be like "stop here something", where something can change from file to file.
When trying to read this new file with the code above it throws an error:

```
Error in while (line != match) { : argument is of length zero
```

and line is empty.

```
line
character(0)
```

I've tried using collapse and grep, but with the same error.

```
match<-paste("stop","here", collapse = "|")
while(line!=grep(match, line)){
```

Is there any way to work around this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `grepl` instead of `grep` since it returns directly a `logical`

```
x <- file("file.txt", "r")
line <- readLines(x, 1)
while(!grepl("^stop here.+", line)) {
    line <- readLines(x, 1)
}
```

Comment: there's nothing in this that would make it increment. It just reads the first line over and over in an infinite loop.